# Reverse CSS indentation in Zend Studio 8

Tags: eclipse, zend-studio

I'm working in Zend Studio 8 based on Eclipse and found that with a CSS file open one can easily format the file to be laid out nicely using  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + F*

It works quick in big files.

Is there a reverse function where I can reduce all selector properties to one line, or even the entire file to one line?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correctly, you want something that can compress your CSS.

I'd use a online program like [CSSCompressor](http://www.csscompressor.com/) or [Minify](http://www.minifycss.com/css-compressor/).

Comment: Yes that functionality but in Zend Studio / eclipse

Comment: It doesn't look like it exists. [This forum discussion](http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&p=9146) has some insight, but no solution. A third-party seems to be the only way as of now.